# State space and linearization

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system

I have a question about state space representation. How can I represent an equation in which I have only the second and first derivatives? For example

[image: equation]

where $u$ is the control input.

If I put $x_1=x$ and $x_2=\dot{x}$ I will not have $x_1$ in my state space representation, and when finding equilibrium points or Jacobian to check controllability, I will obtain zero in the partial derivatives corresponding to $x_1$. Is there a way to overcome this with a more suitable state representation?
 I'm not sure how to solve this problem as I have to linearize the system around an operating point using SS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem with the zeros?

Comment: Well it's just I don't know what to say about the stability of the system in this case or how to find out its equilibrium points, nor how to design a feedback controller for this system, control is not my background and is a little bit difficult to me to get this kind of tricky questions, as I can solve "normal" nonlinear systems. So I'm thinking I could be wrong in my SS representation, or there is a way I can solve the rest of my exercise coming from this.

Comment: You need to provide more info. about what you are trying to do and what you are trying to control/design. Is your state $x,\dot{x}$ or just $\dot{x}$, does $u$ have some nominal value, etc, etc...

Comment: Pitifully I do not have much more info than this. The equation is intended to rule the motion of a plane, what I call x is its attitude angle, and I have to put the equation in state space form, use linearization to analyze the stability of the system and develop feedback control for the system to track a reference angle, so x is what I want to control.

Comment: Well, if you need to control $x$ then you have no choice but to include it in the state space representation. However, I am still not clear about why you think this is a problem with the representation.

Comment: Well what I don't get is how to manage to make the state appear in the state space matrix, because the given equation is written just in terms of the first and second derivatives. If I use x1 and x2 (sorry, I don't know well how to edit this) as states, the state matrix will be only in terms of x2. So for the controller I've been thinking I could include an additional state, but I'm not sure if I can do that.

Comment: Can you measure $x$ or some linear functional of $x,\dot{x}$?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Is it possible to "create" a state with the difference between the reference and the measured signal?

Comment: Again, I really don't know what you are trying to do, but if you can measure $x$ you can build an observer to estimate $\dot{x}$. The reference signal must be an input???

Comment: I also don't know exactly what I'm trying to do lol. The exercise is stated as I wrote above, it doesn't give more information. Do you think it's not clear enough? so maybe I could go and ask my lecturer for some clarifications.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help since I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No worries pal. I just want to solve this exercise haha, but the state not appearing in the equation has become a pain in the ass, I just don't know how to include it/make it appear. Thanks very much for your help and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By selecting $x_1=x$ and $x_2=\dot{x}$ you can write

$$\begin{align*}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= k_1 x_1 (1 - |x_1|) + k_2 u
\end{align*}$$

Now the fixed points are $(0, 0), (1, 0), (-1, 0)$. The Jacobian around $(1, 0)$ (as an example) is

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ k_1(1 - 2 x_1) & 0 \end{bmatrix} |_{x_1=1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -k_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$